# Initial load of Neo4j db from a xml file

Tags: neo4j

Can a xml ( and the relationship it has between entities ) be used to initially populate a Neo4j db?

Can Neo4j or some graph db automatically parse out the relationship between the entities, and then load up the db. I guess, I can later add more details to the relationship?

P.S.: I am reading up on Neo4j, but this can be any graph db.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [graphML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML) which can be loaded into almost any graphdb using the blueprints [GraphML loader](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphML-Reader-and-Writer-Library)

Comment: You have an example with the neo4j server at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph