# How to read/load XML files into neo4j database

Tags: xml, neo4j

I wanted to create nodes and relationships for XML data file. Is it possible to do in neo4j?

Does neo4j read the XML file to create nodes and relationships? if yes, how can i achieve it?

How to load XML file into neo4j database?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**2018 Update** -- users should look at [APOC's methods of loading XML](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_xml).   What's below this update is the original answer.

---

If your XML happens to be GraphML, you can use the [Tinkerpop GraphML Reader](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphML-Reader-and-Writer-Library) to read that XML.  Note that this requires other libraries for neo4j that are in the tinkerpop stack, essentially you'd be reading GraphML using blueprints, and then writing it to your neo4j graph.

If you're referring to any custom kind of XML schema, then the answer is that no, you can't do this easily by default.   XML is a hierarchical structure, and there probably isn't even a neat mapping of elements in the XML tree to the nodes of your needed neo4j graph.   You would first need to transform the XML you're using into GraphML, or into CSV, and then load using one of the existing load methods.

Your other alternative is to write custom code that parses the XML, and then generates new nodes using the Neo4J java API.

Comment: I gone through the GraphML concept. It is saying GraphML consists of an xml which has graph tag,within that it has node and edge tags. Is it like the xml which has different structure with different tags can't be treated ad graph ML? Is it possible to conver custom xml into graphMl using any tools ? Also at the end you told to use custom code to parse the XML. Can i do it using java?

Comment: You can use java to parse the XML, yes.  There aren't tools out there to convert any kind of XML to GraphML.  It really depends on what kind of XML you're dealing with.  Probably some XML languages have graphml conversion tools, others don't.  If it's your custom XML, you're going to end up writing custom code.  Now, you can either write that code to go from your XML -> GraphML and then load that, or you can write code to skip GraphML and load straight from your XML but either way, you'll be writing code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some of the doubts. Suppose If I decide not to use GraphML and write a java code to parse the xml file, then in java code itself do i need to define nodes and relationships? Or how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out GraphML as answered in this question [Initial load of Neo4j db from a xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124216/initial-load-of-neo4j-db-from-a-xml-file)

and the Neo4j Shell Tools: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command